# Is the table created in database memory if there is no DbSet property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is my DbContext

```
public class MyDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<MyDatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Buyer> Buyers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Sale> Sales { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SalesPoint> SalesPoints { get; set; }
    //public DbSet<ProvidedProduct> ProvidedProducts { get; set; }
}
```

This is my SalesPoints class

```
public partial class SalesPoint
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ProvidedProduct> ProvidedProducts { get; set; }
}
```

This is my ProvidedProduct class

```
public class ProvidedProduct
{
   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ProductQuantity { get; set; }
}
```

So the question is, is table ProvidedProduct stored in the database? For when I delete a row in table SalesPoints, and add a new one, the element ids do not come from the last ProvidedProduct element, but from the deleted ProvidedProduct element. That is, it was:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "OZON",
"providedProducts": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "productId": 2,
    "productQuantity": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "productId": 3,
    "productQuantity": 1
  }
]
},
```

then delete this table row and add a new one

```
    {
"id": 1,
"name": "OZON",
"providedProducts": [
  {
    "id": 3,
    "productId": 2,
    "productQuantity": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "productId": 3,
    "productQuantity": 1
  }
]
},
```

and the element id equals 3 4, not 1 2, so it seems to me that the table ProvidedProducts is still stored in the database, although the "//public DbSet ProvidedProducts { get; set; }" property is commented out. Tell me who knows. Thanks a lot. Peace to the world.
I hope I formulated my idea correctly, may google translate help me

Answer (score 0):

The declared DbSets within your DbContext Class (MyDatabaseContext) will be all the tables. This means you should remove ProvidedProducts from SalesPoint class and uncomment the commented DbSet in your MyDatabaseContext class.